# JQuery не добавляет больше одной записи

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста.Есть такой скрипт

```
function submitComment(id) {
    var sText = $('#text').val();
    if (sText) {
        $.post('photos/post_comment.php', { action: 'accept_comment',text: sText, id: id },
            function(data){
                if (data != '1') {
                    $('#comments_list').fadeOut(0, function () {
                        $(this).html(data);
                        $(this).fadeIn(0);
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#comments_warning2').fadeIn(0, function () {
                        $(this).fadeOut(0);
                    });
                }
            }
        );
    } else {
        $('#comments_warning1').fadeIn(100, function () {
            $(this).fadeOut(100);
        });
    }
};
```

При первом добавлении комментария записывается все правильно в базу данных, а при последующем не ищет id фотографии.Подскажите пожалуйста где не правильно.

Comment: @Andrey Kartavtsev, В вашем коде, единственное, что указывает хоть на какую-то связь с проблемой в вопросе "*не ищет id фотографии*" - это слово "photos" в пути к обработчику. Где и что должно искать, какие фотографии и как они вообще связаны с этим сценарием - не ясно.

Comment: Смотрите есть две таблицы в бд. images, там есть поле id_img и есть таблица comments, там есть поле id_img_cm, вот при вводе комментария все добавляется и выводится, но только один раз во второй раз он не ищет ид фотографии, я думаю где то здесь проблема

         if (data != '1') {